# PHP Autoloader doesn't find class in the same directory inherited via extends

Tags: php

I am getting an error when trying to use an autoloader for dynamic loading of the classes I need to use. I've tried a few things, but it fails.

I guess it must be some very silly error in setting up directories, but I have already tried to remove or insert relative paths, "Use"'s, etc.

How can I proceed?

**Error on /admin/index.php**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Connection' not found in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/common/Class/Database/Sql.php:11
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/common/autoload.php(22):
>   require_once() #1 [internal function]: {closure}('Database/Sql') #2
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/common/Class/App/Specialty.php(11):
>   spl_autoload_call('Database\Sql') #3
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/common/autoload.php(22):
>   require_once('/Applications/X...') #4 [internal function]:
>   {closure}('App/Specialty') #5
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/index.php(11):
>   spl_autoload_call('App\Specialty') #6
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php(21):
>   include('/Applications/X...') #7 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/common/Class/Database/Sql.php on
>   line 11

**Dir Structure**

```
- /Common
   - /Class
      - /Database
         - Connection.php
         - Query.php
         - Sql.php
      - /App
         - Specialty.php
      - autoload.php
 - /admin
   - index.php
```

**And the files...**

**/admin/index.php**

```
$objTeste = new App\Specialty();
$objTeste->save();
```

**/common/autoload.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className){

    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $dir = __DIR__."/Class";

    $className = str_replace('\\', $ds, $className);

    $file = "{$dir}{$ds}{$className}.php";

    if (is_readable($file)) require_once $file;

});
```

**/common/Class/App/Specialty.php**

```
class Specialty extends Database\Sql
{
    use Database\Query;
    ...
}
```

**/common/Class/Database/Sql.php**

```
class Sql extends Connection
{
    ...
}
```

**/common/Class/Database/Query.php**

```
trait Query
{
    ...
}
```

**/common/Class/Database/Sql.php**

```
class Sql extends Connection
{
    ...
}
```

**/common/Class/Database/Connection.php**
    class Connection
    {
        ...
    }

An important detail: I print_r() inside the autoloader to find out if the class path was being generated correctly, and guess what... it was!

```
print_r($file);
# /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Common/Class/Database/Connection.php
```

**Test if the $file is readable**

```
if(is_readable($file)){
    print_r($file." found<br>");
}
else{
    print_r($file." not found<br>");
}

# Result: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Common/Class/Database/Connection.php found
```

Comment: @Jeto sorry, you're right. I cut off a piece of the result for considering it irrelevant. But the correct result contemplates the absolute path. I've edited the question right now!

Comment: @Jeto i tried to use with upper/lowercase. Now, all the references are using the uppercase Class name. And the same error persists.

Comment: @Jeto nvm, i just copy/paste a old print_r. But there was a uppercase Class. I tried to get if $path is_readable... i'll edit the question with the result.

Comment: Since you're referencing `Database\Sql` and stuff like this, PHP is interpreting them (the parts before the last one) as namespaces. Are you using any `namespace` declarations on top of your files?

Comment: I dont! Im trying to do it right now...

Comment: Should be whatever comes after `Class/` in your folder structure. E.g. `Connection` should be in the `Database` namespace, `Specialty` in the `App` namespace, etc.

Comment: Is the 1st time that im trying to separate my classes in different directories. With namespaces, that works! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using backslashes in your class names, PHP interprets everything that comes before the last one as a [namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

For instance, when you're doing this:

```
class Specialty extends Database\Sql
```

PHP reads this as "define a class `Specialty` that extends a class `Sql` present in the `Database` namespace".

So to fix your issues (and make your code cleaner in the meantime), simply add the proper namespace declaration on top of your files, based on whatever comes after `Class/` in your folder structure (since that's the root folder your autoloader is using).

e.g.:

```
namespace Database;

class Sql {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Works with: namespace App; class Specialty extends \Database\Sql {